# Many to Many relationship query. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how I can do a query within a query. (if that even makes sense) I want to grab all the activities. For each activity I want to get the count of users that did the activity. Then I want to order all the activities in DESC order based on the amount of users that did each activity. I'm basically making a "Popular Activities Page" where I show the all activities starting with the activity done by the most users.

I have 3 main tables for this

**users**

```
| id | name | password | email | created_at |
```

**activities**

```
| id | title | description | created_at |
```

**resource** This is a table I'm using for posts which shows which user did which activity. (Users can show what activities they did, and attach media and locations to the post)

```
| id | user_id | activity_id | media_id | location_id | created_at |
```

Here are my models for each table

**User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * get the activities associated with the given user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Acme\Activities\Activity', 'resource', 'activity_id');
    }

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Resource\Resource');
    }

    public function media()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Media\Media');
    }

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Locations\Location');
    }
}
```

**Activity Model**

```
class Activity extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'activities';


    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Resource\Resource', 'resource_id');
    }

    /**
     * get the users associated with the given activity card
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Acme\Users\User', 'resource', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

**Resource Model**

```
class Resource extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'resource';


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\Users\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\Activities\Activity', 'activity_id');
    }

    public function media()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Acme\Media\Media', 'media_id');
    }

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\Locations\Location', 'location_id');
    }
}
```

I know I can get all activities using

```
Activity::get()
```

I can get a user count for a specific activity using

```
User::whereHas('resource', function($q) use ($activity_id){
    $q->where('activity_id', $activity_id);
})->get()->count();
```

but I don't know how I can put all of this together in order to get all Activities sorted by user count, starting with the activity with the highest user count.

How would I make this query using eloquent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
Resource::select(DB::raw('*, COUNT(distinct(user_id)) as user_count'))->group_by('activity_id')->order_by('user_count', 'desc')->get();
```

You could then do this

```
$results = Resource::select(DB::raw('*, COUNT(distinct(user_id)) as user_count'))->group_by('activity_id')->order_by('user_count', 'desc')->get();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $activity = Activity::where('id','=',$result->activity_id)->first();
    // do stuff to display data for this activity like
    // $activity->title or $activity->description
    $count = $result->user_count; 
}
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect! you are a life saver!

Comment: please verify results. I did not test this, just whipped it together on a whim. Something I thought may be an issue would be that it would count all `user_id` before being grouped. make sure the `user_count` that is a result of this is the count for that specific `activity_id`.

Comment: Ah yes I just tried it out. It is grabbing all user_id, including duplicates. I need it to be distinct with user_id and only get a count of users that did each activity, not every time a user did an activity

Comment: i have this example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3dcf/3 - the only columns you actually need to use are activity_id and user_count. Looks like it is working to me. No need to know the user_ids if all you want is the activity and it's count.

Comment: P.S. grouping by activity_id makes the user_id data useless anyways.

Comment: Well the thing is I have a list of activities that have a number showing the amount of users on my site that did the activity. A user can do an activity more than one time, but i do not count how many times each user did the activity, I'm only concerned with how many users did the activity. so if John does an activity 4 times and Bill does the same activity 5 times the count for that activity is only 2. because only 2 users did the activity. and what I'm trying to do is order the activities by the user count.

Comment: so there are multiple rows on resource table with same user_id and same activity_id ?

Comment: is there a way to group the user_ids belonging to the activity and then get the count?

Comment: change this part `DB::raw('*, COUNT(user_id) as user_count')` to `DB::raw('*, COUNT(*) as user_count')` - i will update answer. check results please.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea84bf/1 - if you look, user 1 did activity 2, 3 separate times and all activity '3' instances were counted by the `group by`. so this should work now.

Comment: i tried `DB::raw('*, COUNT(distinct(user_id)) as user_count')` and that worked!

Comment: distinct actually doesn't work from my test here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea84bf/2 - it only counts activity "2" 3 times but when you look in the schema builder on top left you can see activity "2" happened 5 times. use count(*) like shown in edit.

Comment: No thats what i want. I don't want to know how many time the activity was done but how many people did the activity. so if user 1 did activity 4, 6 times, and user 2 did activity 4, 9 times. then activity 4 has a count of 2

Comment: oh, then distinct is what you want :) sorry, misinterpreted the request :) glad you got what you needed!

Comment: yes thank you very much i would not have gotten far with out you. update your answer to distinct() so i may accept it :)